# How to test counter_cache with test::unit and mocha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, mocha.js, counter-cache

I'm curious if i can mock out somehow the testing of a counter cache.
Now I'm creating all the records to test the counter_cache. Is there any good practices to test counter cache effectively?

**Edit:**
I'm just interested in testing that, the counter cache exists on a certain association.

Comment: why would you want to test counter_cache? you'd be testing a framework feature. there will be tests for that in the Rails test suite. Your tests should only cover your application, not the framework it builds on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the `:counter_cache` option, ActiveRecord defines 2 callbacks ([source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/40afcade0dc1450e765a91fc15a6ac6d442c9826/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1571-1591)). You can use Mocha to check if the callback is executed.

```
instance.expects(:belongs_to_counter_cache_after_create_for_MODELNAME).returns(true)
```

Comment: That's a neat solution, I saw these dynamic methods, but I didn't realized that I can do this way.

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry, reload your object with counter_cache and check if it's increment.

Comment: that's what i'm doing, just wanted to know if I can avoid hitting the database.